# Linking multiple Excel documents to an Access DB

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have ~200 Excel workbooks each with a unique name, in its own folder, something like `C:\docs\daily\XXXX\XXXX_Daily_Report_20150920.xls`, where XXXX is just an alphanumeric identifier and the date is obviously just today's date. 
I need to get one cell (the same cell, "I2") from all 200+ Excel workbooks every single day.

I know you can link Excel workbooks to Access but I can't figure out a way to make it link to a different workbook each day and I'm wondering if there is a query to simply get that one cell instead of linking the entire Excel workbook.

Right now I have Excel VBA that opens each Excel file and copies and pastes it into the corresponding row/column in my workbook...but since it does this 200+ times I'm wondering if Access will have a faster solution.

Is there any way to write a query/macro in Access that will link the cell I2 from each day's new report (so tomorrow's would be "XXXX Daily Report 20150921.xls") and just populate a table with XXXX in the first column and the value of I2 in the second?

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please let me know - and accept the answer if it worked for you.  If it isn't what you need, add a comment and I may be able to clarify the answer.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function import()

source_date = InputBox("date (yyyymmdd)")
Set db = CurrentDb()
db.Execute ("delete * from [DailyData]")

Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder_list = FSO.GetFolder("C:\docs\daily").subfolders
For Each Fldr In folder_list
    Source = Fldr.Name
    SourceFile = "c:\docs\daily\" & Source & "\" & Source & "_daily_reports_" & source_date & ".xlsm"
    Set WB = app.workbooks.Open(SourceFile)
    amount = WB.sheets("sheet1").range("I2").Value
    SQL = "Insert into [DailyData] (source, amount) select '" & Source & "'," & amount
    db.Execute (SQL)
    WB.Close
    Next Fldr

MsgBox ("done")

End Function
```

This takes all the files for a specific date and puts the input into a table called DailyData, with fields for Source and Amount.

Note - modified 9/22 to eliminate the inside loop and If block - this assumes every folder will have a file for the current day's update.  If not, you may want to verify that the file exists before you try to open it.